# setting RGBA values in inline styles

Tags: reactjs

To set a color in a React inline style to an RGBA value I can at least use string interpolation in ES6:

```
<div style={{color: `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`}}>test</div
```

Does React support objects instead of a string here? Something similar to it supporting numbers where pixel units are assumed for styles like `width` etc. For example:

```
<div style={{color: {r, g, b, a}}}>test</div
```

Comment: Nothing to do with OP post re: objects, but for normal use backtick quotes worked for me ```style={{backgroundColor: `rgba(4,120,87,1)`}}>```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. React supports no such function. I suggest either:

1. Use string interpolation as you've done above.
2. Write your own rgba() function.
3. Use a third party library. I recommend polished which has just such a function. https://polished.js.org/docs/#rgba

Answer (score 1):

Make your color  a constant, and put it in backticks, for example:
const blueColor = `rgba(64, 107, 169, 1)`;